# Pyinstaller pynput module not found

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have pyinstaller installed I have configured the PATH for my scripts, and when I compile using this command in cmd:

C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\Projects\Annoying Mouse>pyinstaller -F AnnoyingMouse.py

When I run the .exe file a terminal appears saying pynput module not found! PLS HELP

```
from pynput.mouse import Controller
import keyboard, random

mk = Controller()
counter = 0
random_number = 0

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("n") and keyboard.is_pressed("m"):
        break

    if (counter == 20000):
        random_number = random.randint(1, 5)

        if (random_number == 1):
            mk.move(0, -100)
        elif (random_number == 2):
            mk.move(0, 100)
        elif (random_number == 3):
            mk.move(100, 0)
        elif (random_number == 4):
            mk.move(-100, 0)

        counter = 0

    counter += 1
    print(counter)
```

Comment: Try adding 'import pynput' at the top?